# Spring Data Neo4j anotated query not returning desired results

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am not able to get data from `neo4j server` using the spring data annotated query, though data exists in the server, also if i use the same query and paste it in `neo4j console` it works well and returns me the below data:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n                                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[25503]{id:1388107845,name:"Cricket",__type__:"com.domain.Sport"}     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The anotated spring data query is

```
@Query("match n where n.__type__='com.domain.Sport' and n.name='{0}' return n;")
public Sport getSportWithName(String sportName);
```

Any insights on what is wrong with this query.

Comment: Are you using Spring data to connect to the server, or an embedded DB?

Comment: what versions do you use? SDN and Neo4j server? They should match.

Comment: @TheSageMage, we are using spring data to connect to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quote parameters:

```
@Query("match n where n.__type__='com.domain.Sport' and n.name={0} return n")
public Sport getSportWithName(String sportName);
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael removing the quotes made that working, we are using `Neo4j's 2.0.0-M03` and 
`Spring data neo4j is 2.2.1.RELEASE`. Is this a version mismatch problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @TypeAlias on com.domain.Sport?

If so, try using the alias value in the query:

```
@Query("match n where n.__type__='Sport' and n.name='{0}' return n;")
public Sport getSportWithName(String sportName);
```

Comment: we are not using `@TypeAlias` on `com.domain.Sport`, one thing i already mentioned that this works on neo4j web console.